# XML-Code Change Value of Node - How is the displayed Code correct?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument, xml-attribute

I Need to Code an XML-File in C# using XMLDocument. I extract the desired XML-File and only Need to insert some Elements i Need to add.

The EXPECTED Output should look like this:

```
<service>
   <coding>
       <system value="https://somethingichanged" />
         <code value="myvalue" />
    </coding>
</service>
```

However, my Output Looks like this:

```
<service>
    <coding>
         <system>https://somethingichanged</system>
        <code>myvalue</code>
    </coding>
</service>
```

Here is my Code:

```
string[] tag = new string[] { "service", "coding", "system", "code", "http://URI"};
XmlElement Service = m_XMLDoc.CreateElement(tag[0], tag[4]);
XmlElement Coding = m_XMLDoc.CreateElement(tag[1], tag[4]);
Service.AppendChild(Coding);

//Fill Element
XmlNode System = m_XMLDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, tag[2], tag[4]);
XmlNode Code = m_XMLDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, tag[3], tag[4]);
System.InnerText = "https://somethingichanged";
Coding.AppendChild(System);

Code.InnerText = myTSS[i].ToString();
Coding.AppendChild(Code);
```

How does the correct Code look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should created attribuites, not xml elements.

So use:

```
System.Attributes.Append( m_XMLDoc.CreateAttribute("value", "https://somethingichanged"));

Code.Attributes.Append( m_XMLDoc.CreateAttribute("value", myTSS[i].ToString()));
```

instead of

```
System.InnerText = "https://somethingichanged";
Code.InnerText = myTSS[i].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net LINQ to XML makes it much easier to achieve in one single statement of code.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    string[] tag = new string[] { "service", "coding", "system", "code", "http://URI"};

    XElement xml = new XElement(tag[0],
                        new XElement(tag[1],
                            new XElement(tag[2], new XAttribute("value", tag[4])),
                            new XElement(tag[3], new XAttribute("value", "myvalue")))
                        );
}
```

> Output XML:

```
<service>
  <coding>
    <system value="http://URI" />
    <code value="myvalue" />
  </coding>
</service>
```